# SQL Server Memory Optimized Data and FILESTREAM Data File is very large

Tags: sql-server

For increasing the speed of a SQL query, we decide to use in-memory table.

The in-memory table is very simple and light, it contains about 7000 records.

The problem is the FILESTREAM Data File is very large for a small in-memory table.

See bellow image:

[image]

Why this FILESTREAM Data File is large?
How can I shrink or empty it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far a I understand [FILESTREAM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filestream-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) store binary data so it's not directly connected to in-memory table.

Maybe some other problem happening in here or your database simply have a lot of binary data like a word document or image files.

Maybe the filestream file size is large because the older filestream version is not being released [see here](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/filestream-garbage-collection/)

Comment: It's necessary to enable FileStream to use in-memory table.

Comment: Is filestream data file already there before you use the in-memory table? if yes, at what size do you remember the last time you see it?

Comment: We didn't use FileStream File before creating of in-memory table,we created the FileStream File for in-memory table. Our tables in the database have not binary column type.

Comment: When you first create the filestream file, what is the size of the file?

Comment: I didn't attend to the first creation size. I thinks it was about 1 GB on initial but it is about 2 GB now! Why is it large?

Comment: read here for a probable cause (the way the filestream works) https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/filestream-garbage-collection/

Comment: Some suggest use checkpoint for full recovery mode https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/746021/Release-FileStream-space?PageIndex=3

Comment: I changed the recovery model to simple then I shrinked the database but it has not effect on files size.

Comment: use sp_filestream_force_garbage_collection  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/filestream-and-filetable-sp-filestream-force-garbage-collection?view=sql-server-2017